# Slice all strings in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, slice

Is there a Pythonic way to slice all strings in a list?

Suppose I have a list of strings:

```
list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

And I want just the last 2 characters from each string:

```
list2 = ['oo', 'ar', 'az']
```

How can I get that?

I know I can iterate thru the list and take `list[i][-2:]` from each one, but that doesn't seem very Pythonic.

Less generally, my code is:

```
def parseIt(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

   result = [i.split(',') for i in lines[]]
```

...except I only want to split `lines[i][20:]` from each line (not the whole line).

Comment: What is wrong with `[word[1:] for word in lst]`? That's pretty straight forward. Also, your code is dealing with a file where each row is comma separated?

Comment: @idjaw: Yes, that's it; thanks. More precisely that answers the first part of my question and tells me how to solve the second part, which I think is `result = [i[20:].split(',') for i in lines]`. Make it an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: But what final output are you looking for? `[i[20:].split(',') for i in lines]` seems a bit strange. What does each row look like from `lines`? And what *exactly* are you looking to get as a final result?

Comment: @idjaw `[i[20:].split(',') for i in lines]` may seem strange, but it gives exactly what I wanted. It's a log file where the first 20 bytes of each line are a header/timestamp, and then the rest of each line is comma-separated.

Comment: No problem. I posted the solution for you.

Comment: Newbie here: what is "pythonic"?

Comment: @AllDani https://www.google.com/#q=what%20is%20pythonic

Comment: LOL - question closed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mentioned that you can do `list[i][-2:]` for transforming the list per your specification, but what you are actually looking for is:

```
[word[1:] for word in lst]
```

Furthermore, for the code sample you provided where you are looking to slice 20 characters from the beginning, the solution would be the same:

```
result = [i[20:].split(',') for i in lines]
```